# Sorting through Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays

Please tell my errors I am using bubble sort method to sort an array, i want it using pointer plz correct my mistakes, i m new to c++.  I think my mistake is in sorting condition.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  //sorting

  int arr[5];

  int *ptr;
  ptr = arr;
  int temp;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cin >> *(ptr+i);
  }


  for (int i = 0; i<5;i++) {
    for (int z = 0; z<4; z++) {
      if (*(ptr+1) < *ptr) {
        temp = *ptr;
        *ptr = *(ptr+1);
        *(ptr+1) = temp;
      }
      *(ptr++);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << *(ptr+i) << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your program ?

Comment: As the now-deleted answer said, `*(ptr++)` should be `ptr++`. It will make a difference when `ptr` points to one-past-the-end and you try to dereference that.

Comment: i also tried using ptr but still error

Comment: At the end of the `for (int z = 0; z<4; z++)` loop, `ptr` will be equal to `arr + 5`. Then the outer loop will increment `i` by 1 and continue. What happens to `ptr` then?

Comment: Your bubble sort algorithm itself is wrong.

Comment: I tried using simple array without pointers it worked but not working through pointers

Comment: @chris: since this is postincrement, if the pointer isn't moved *beyond* past-the-array it will be technically okay. but i agree with your general reaction. the dereferencing is completely unnecessary, could in some other context very well have been problematic, and indicates that the OP is compiling with very low warning level or, worse, is ignoring warnings.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Oops, the parentheses screwed up my logic, thanks.

Comment: I have fixed it now this is where i made changes

Comment: Your ptr goes beyond 5 int items.

Comment: I have fixed my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are sorting the array in ascending order; when doing that, you are doing several things wrong:

1. you are aways swaping *ptr and *(ptr+1) -> you need to add z to this equation or the pointer will never increment.
2. after the first iteration you have the largest element in the array on the last position, so now you need to stop just before the last position with the comparisions

The code should look like thins:

```
for (int i = 0; i<5;i++) {
    for (int z = 0; z<4-i; z++) {
      if (*(ptr+z+1) < *(ptr+z)) {
        temp = *(ptr+z);
        *(ptr+z) = *(ptr+z+1);
        *(ptr+z+1) = temp;
      }     
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the logic,

Answer (score 3):

reset your Pointer ptr after your loop with "z"
Set it back to ptr = arr;

Comment: it is giving output but not in ascending order

Comment: So how do you think you'd make it go in non-ascending order?

Comment: Thanks I have used ur logic it worked now I did this ptr = &arr[0]; in my sorting condition plus before last condition and instead of *ptr++ i used ptr++ Thanks a lot